# Adam falling because Satan swore by the name of God

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I cannot quote a source now, but I once heard a story, where some son (or perhaps grandson) of Adam was asking him something like, “O father, why did you have to eat that fruit! We wouldn't be here now!” And the answer was something to the effect of, “I would have never thought that someone would swear by the name of Allah, and lie!”

Is this some narration perhaps from Jewish culture, or is it mentioned in hadith literature?

Comment: I have never heard this story before. However, there is this hadith: https://sunnah.com/urn/1250800. The question to Adam (AS) is the same, but he answers something else.

Comment: I don't know what Hadith is this but Shayatin did swear by Allah to them Al-A'raf 7:21

وَقَاسَمَهُمَاۤ اِنِّيْ لَكُمَا لَمِنَ النّٰصِحِيْنَ ۙ 

And he swore [by Allah ] to them, "Indeed, I am to you from among the sincere advisors."

Comment: @Yusha you should post an answer. Comments are not meant to last for ever as their purpose is clarification **not answering**. See also in [our Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/answers-on-comment-section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the exact words, but the meaning has been narrated in the exegesis of the verse:

> وقاسمهما إني لكما لمن الناصحين   فدلاهما بغرور
>
> And he swore [by Allah ] to them, "Indeed, I am to you from among the sincere advisors." So he made them fall, through deception.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:21-22](http://legacy.quran.com/7/21-22)</sup>

> عن السدي: ألم أنهكما عن تلكما الشجرة قال آدم: رب إنه حلف لي بك، ولم أكن أظنك أن أحدا من خلقك يحلف بك إلا صادقا
>
> As-Suddi narrated: ... Adam said: O Lord! He swore by You, and I did not think that anyone from your creation would swear by you except the truth.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Abi Hatim](https://shamela.ws/book/8658/1443)</sup>

> عن ابن عباس، قال: ... ولكن وعزتك ما حسبت أن أحدا يحلف بك كاذبا (Tabari)
>
> قال ابن عباس: غرهما باليمين، وكان آدم لا يظن أن أحدا يحلف بالله كاذبا
>
> Ibn Abbas said: He deceived him by his oath, and Adam did not think that anyone would swear falsely by Allah.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabari](https://shamela.ws/book/7798/17240#p1), [Zad al-masir](https://shamela.ws/book/23619/702#p12) , [Tafsir al-Razi](https://shamela.ws/book/23635/2420#p1), [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura7-aya22.html) etc.</sup>

It is not a hadith from the Prophet ﷺ, although it may be possible that they received it from the Prophet or from Israelite traditions.